# How does this pattern work: 'test/e2e/**/*.spec.js'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, filepath

I saw this pattern used in a configuration file for [protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/).

```
specs: [
  'test/e2e/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

To mean it means "all files inside *test/e2e*". What kind of pattern is this? I think it's not regex because of those unescaped slashes. Especially, why is there `**` in the middle, not just `test/e2e/*.spec.js`?

I tried using the search engine, but did not find anything useful probably because the asterisks don't work very well in search engines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What kind of pattern is this?

It is called "[glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)". The module [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) is a popular implementation for Node, and appears to be the one used by Protractor.

> Especially, why is there "**" in the middle, not just "test/e2e/*.spec.js"?

`**` means it can match sub-directories. It's like a wildcard for sub-directories.

For example, `test/e2e/*.spec.js` would match `test/e2e/example.spec.js`, but not `test/e2e/subdir/example.spec.js`. However `test/e2e/**/*.spec.js` matches both.

Answer (score 5):

[It is called "glob" syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). Glob is a tool which allows files to be specified using a series of wildcards.

- `*.js` means "everything in a folder with a `js` extension.
- `**` means "descendant files/folders.
- `**/*.js` means "descendant files with a `js` extension in descendant folders."
- `test/e2e/**/*.spec.js'` means the above, starting in the `test/e2e/` directory.

So, for example, given this file system:

```
test/e2e/foo/a.spec.js <-- matches
test/e2e/foo/butter.js <-- does not include "spec.js"
test/e2e/bar/something.spec.js <-- matches
test/other/something-different.spec.js <-- not in /test/e2e
```

The final pattern would match:

```
test/e2e/foo/a.spec.js
test/e2e/bar/something.spec.js
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a globbing pattern. Most javascript things using globbing patterns seem to be based around the [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) npm package. It's worth taking a look at the documentation as there are some handy hints in there for when you have more complex situations.

The path you are asking about will match any file ending `.spec.js` in **any** subdirectory under `test/e2e`